# How to simulate packet loss in ssh connection using scp

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, vpn, scp

I'd like to observe the durability of a new VPN tunnel protocol called wireGuard on an unstable network environment in both macOS and Linux platforms when transferring a large chunk of data from one node to another.

Notice that wireGuard is working under UDP, and I wanted to get a feeling how it's dealt with packet loss to some extent.

Is there any method that can set the network interface to drop some percentage of the packets during this remote copying session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Linux with `iptables`, something along the lines of:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.02 -j DROP
```

or

```
iptables -A INPUT -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.02 -j DROP
```

Notes:

- The above commands affect all packets processed by the `OUTPUT` (or `INPUT` respectively) chain of the `filter` table. You will probably want to use `-p` (protocol) and e.g. `--dport` (destination port) to target specific connection(s) only:

  ```
  iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 1234 -m …
  ```
- While testing different variants, remember to remove unneeded rules instead of stacking them. To remove a rule invoke the same `iptables …` command, but with `-D` in place of `-A`.

---

I don't know `nftables` well enough. I have found this: [*How to drop packets based on a probability with `nftables`?*](https://serverfault.com/q/971826)

---

I don't know macOS *at all*. In my research I have encountered `pfctl` along with `dnctl`. I have found this for OSX: [*How to drop packets randomly*](https://serverfault.com/q/753398). I totally don't know if `dnctl` used in the answer there can be used in macOS nowadays. Sorry.

<sup>Moving the "macOS part" to a separate question (which I believe may be asked on [apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com)), while leaving only the "Linux part" here may be a good strategy.</sup>